# R: Subset by multiple criteria filter

Tags: r

I have df1:

```
City        Freq
Seattle      20
San Jose     10
SEATTLE       5
SAN JOSE     15
Miami        12
```

I created this dataframe using `table(df)`

I have another df2:

```
City
San Jose 
Miami
```

I want to subset df1 if the city values in df1 equal to those in df2. This df2 is only a sample so I can't use an OR condition ( " | " ) because I have many different criteria. Perhaps I could convert this df2 into a vector.. but I'm not sure how to do this. as.vector() doesn't seem to work.

I thought about using

```
subset(df1, City == df2)
```

but this gives me errors.

Also, if you guys could get me a way to make this case insensitive such that "San Jose" and "SAN JOSE" are added together, that would be even better!

If I use "toupper / tolower", I get the error: `invalid multibyte`

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `df2` is presumebly a `data.frame` (?) and you can't filter by a data frame,  you need to select the correct column, for example, `df2$V1`. You should also use `%in%` instead of `==` in order to compare against several values. Re your second question, take a look at `tolower` or `toupper`

Answer (score 1):

Here are few more methods

### R Code:

```
# Method 1: using dplyr package
library(dplyr)
filter(df1, tolower(df1$City) %in% tolower(df2$City))
df1 %>% filter(tolower(df1$City) %in% tolower(df2$City))

# Method 2: using which function
df1[ which( tolower(df1$City) %in% tolower(df2$City)) , ]

# Method 3:
df1[(tolower(df1$City) %in% tolower(df2$City)), ]
```

### Output:

```
      City Freq
2 San Jose   10
4 SAN JOSE   15
5    Miami   12
```

Hope this helps.